# Difference between memset and _strnset

Tags: c++, c, memset

I can't figure out what exactly is the difference between the two following implementations:

```
char str[20] = "Hello World";
_strnset(str, '*', 5);
```

and

```
char str[20] = "Hello World";
memset(str, '*', 5);
```

They both produce the following outcome:

Output: ***** World!

Is there a preference between them?

Comment: Note that `strnset` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Everybody knows what memset() does.  When it starts with an _ underscore then you keep your fingers crossed and hope that it still works the way it did 20 years ago, doesn't take an hour removing those underscores when you port and doesn't blow your stack.  Yes, you have a preference.

Comment: `memset(void *p,...)` does not require `p` to point to a string.  `_strnset(char *str, ...)` specifies that `str` point to a string.  [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddwe375(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_strnset` knows it's working with a string, so will respect the null terminator. `memset` does not, so it won't.

As for preference,

- `memset` is in both the C and C++ standards, `_strnset` is in neither.
- if available, `_strnset` can save you from buffer overflows if you write buggy code.

If you know you'll stay on Windows, use `_strnset`. Else `memset`.

Comment: Right.  This sentence from the documentation proves that: "If count is greater than the length of str, the length of str is used instead of count."

Comment: Can I get an example of the null terminator being respected vs not?

Comment: `"Hello World"` has 11 characters, plus 1 byte for the `'\0'`.  So, compare `_strnset(str, '*', 15)` to `memset(str, '*', 15)`.

Comment: @pistachiobk like Max demonstrates, if you pass an `n` larger than the buffer size, `_strnset` is able to detect that because it will stop at the null terminator. `memset` will overrun the buffer, a potentially serious bug.

Comment: Which version of C++ defines `_strnset()`?  I don't believe it is a standard C++ library function (as in ISO/IEC 14882:2014) — it might be available on Windows (or some other platform) by default.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right, I perused the C++ standard and strnset does not appear. Updated answer.

Comment: It seems a deign oversight that the documentation ([Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddwe375.aspx)) of `_strnset(char *str, int c, size_t count)` specifies that `str` point to a _string_.  I'd expect the the function to work on any character array of at least `count` size even if it does not include a null character.

Comment: @Adam Even though it's not a standard, if I plan on staying on Windows, it's safe to say _strnset should be preferred?

Comment: Microsoft would rather you use `_strnset_s`, the "secure" variant that does even more checks. If you're going to stay on Windows I'd use one of those, mainly because eventually you'll want to move to Unicode strings and `memset` isn't going to work on those.